# Cannot use enum values imported from GraphQL Codegen types

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, graphql, graphql-codegen

Whenever I import enums from graphql-codegen generated types and use their values, the app fails to start.

```
import { MyEnum } from 'graphql-types.ts';

let x: MyEnum; // This works
x = MyEnum.MY_ENUM_VALUE; // Whenever I use this code, it fails
```

TypeScript does not show any errors in the code, but the app fails to run showing the error message below.

```
Android Bundling failed

SyntaxError: graphql.types.ts: Identifier 'Document' has already been declared.

export const Document = gql`
...
```

Comment: have you tried naming your  identifier as something other  than Document?

Comment: @DamianGreen How are you able to change these identifiers?

Comment: `export const myQuery = gql``

Comment: @DamianGreen That's what fixed it! If you create an answer, I will accept it.
I needed to use:
`export const name = gql\`
query name (`

instead of:
`export const name = gql\`
query (`

Comment: just saw this.. done :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
export const name = gql`
    query name {
```

instead of:

```
export const name = gql`
    query {
```

Your identifier name is likely clashing with an ambient type definition.